# Using Pandas to calculate stats off certain columns/entries?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm basically trying to grab the max, min, avg, etc from an .csv file using pandas, although I'm getting some weird output. I also want to filter by specific brand. For example, assume there are more entries with the Brand Ford, I would like to print the max of all the Fords.

ex. CSV

```
**Brand**              **Color**           **Price**

  Ford                    Red                  5

 Ferrari                  Blue                 10 

 Chevy                    Green                15
```

My code

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(r'Cars.csv')
df1 = df[['Brand','Price']]

groupby_MAX = df1.groupby(['Brand']).max()
groupby_MIN = df1.groupby(['Brand']).min()
groupby_AVG = df1.groupby(['Brand']).mean()
groupby_STD = df1.groupby(['Brand']).std()
groupby_RNG = (df1.groupby(['Brand']).max() - df1.groupby(['Brand']).min())


print('Max of values, grouped by Brand: ' + str(groupby_MAX))
print('\nMin of values, grouped by Brand: ' + str(groupby_MIN))
```

My output

```
Max of values, grouped by Brand:             Price
Brand         
Ford          5
Ferrari       10
Chevy         15

Min of values, grouped by Brand:             Price
Brand         
Ford         5
Ferrari      10
Chevy        15
```

What I want

```
Stats, grouped by Brand:             
    Brand        Max       Min     Mean   S.Dev 
    Ford          5         5        5      5
    Ferrari       10        10      10      10
    Chevy         15        15      15      15
```

Comment: Did you read the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `.agg` to aggregate several functions on the dataframe.

example:

user-defined range function:

```
def rng(x):
    return x.max() - x.min()
```

use `.agg` with the built-in functions and user-defined function:

`df.groupby(by='Brand').agg(['max', 'min', 'mean', 'std', rng])`

this yields :

```
        Price                  
          max min mean  std rng
Brand                          
Chevy      15  15   15  0.0   0
Ferrari    10  10   10  0.0   0
Ford        5   5    5  0.0   0
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to figure out a way to add range, but this is what I was trying to figure out. What if I just wanted Ferrari?

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you only want the specific brand you can use boolean mask before `.groupby` like `df[df['Brand'] == 'Ferrari'].groupby(by='Brand').agg(['max', 'min', 'mean', 'std', rng])`. CMIIW